# How can i comparing times correctly in 24h format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, datetime

I get an object with times like this:

```js
const times = {
   "sunrise": "Wed Jul 08 2020 05:17:15 GMT+0200", //this is a date object not a string
   "goldenHourEnd:" "Wed Jul 08 2020 06:12:13 GMT+0200",
   "morning": "Wed Jul 08 2020 08:04:20 GMT+0200",
   "solarNoon": "Wed Jul 08 2020 13:35:04 GMT+0200",
   "evening": "Wed Jul 08 2020 19:05:48 GMT+0200",
   "goldenHour": "Wed Jul 08 2020 20:57:55 GMT+0200",
   "sunset": "Wed Jul 08 2020 21:52:53 GMT+0200",
   "nauticalDusk": "Wed Jul 08 2020 23:57:10 GMT+0200"
};
```

At the moment, i am using this function to get the current Phase, based on the current client time:

```js
function getCurrentTimePhase(object) {
  return Object.entries(object)
  .map(([k, v]) => [ k, Date.now() - Date.parse(v) ])
  .reduce((pre, cur) => cur[1] < pre[1] && cur[1] > 0 ? cur : pre)[0];
}
```

The problem is that the function does not always return the current time phase. For Example:

```js
//current client time is Wed Jul 08 2020 01:31:04 GMT+0200
const currentPhase = getCurrentTimePhase(times);
console.log(currentPhase); //output: solarNoon
```

The Function will be returned `solarNoon`. Actually the function should be returned nauticalDusk, because we are still in this phase. The next phase `sunrise` starts at `Wed Jul 08 2020 05:17:15 GMT+0200`, which should be returned when I have passed this time mark and so on.

How can i solve this? Any ideas?

Comment: According to my test, your algorithm gives "sunrise" for any time before "sunrise". A quick fix is to add `["nauticalDusk"]` as 2nd argument to your reduce call: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/46b2p1xo/

Comment: Did you see my fiddle? Does it not work for you?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your effort, but it doesn't really help me. I want to dynamically get the current time phase, based on the current client time...

Comment: Sorry, but that fiddle was hard-coded to demonstrate that it gives the correct result for a time before sunrise; it's not supposed to be used as-is. I even inserted the proper line that uses the current time as a comment. I thought that's obvious, and given that `times` is also hardcoded to only work on July 8th, I didn't think this would be a problem. Again, as I stated in my previous comment, all you need to do is provide `["nauticalDusk"]` as initial value for your `reduce` function.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your answer, I'm sorry if I was unclear about that. You say: all you need to do is provide ["nauticalDusk"] as initial value... what do you mean? What exactly do I have to change about my function? Could you perhaps show me by means of your fiddle? Cause all he's giving me back right now is nauticalDusk at any time

Comment: My bad; I could have sworn that small change fixed it but I guess I didn't check later times after inserting it. What should definitely work is something like `if (Date.now() < Date.parse(times.sunrise)) return "nauticalDusk";`

Answer (score -1):

Running your code and replacing `Date.now()` with `new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 01:31:04 GMT+0200')` the result I get is "sunrise". That's because there is no initial value for the accumulator passed to *reduce*, so the first two elements of `Object.entries(times)` are passed and `['sunrise', 'Wed Jul 08 2020 05:17:15 GMT+0200']` is initially assigned to the accumulator. No current value fits the criteria to replace the initial accumulator so it's returned.

I think the use of *map* is redundant, and *reduce* is inefficient as the loop should stop as soon as a suitable value is found.

The following uses [*findIndex*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the first phase after the passed date (default is the current date and time), then gets the previous phase. If there is no phase either before or after the date, the last phase is used.

I also put in a sort to ensure the entries are suitably ordered.

```js
let times = {
   "sunrise": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 05:17:15 GMT+0200'),
   "goldenHourEnd": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 06:12:13 GMT+0200'),
   "morning": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 08:04:20 GMT+0200'),
   "solarNoon": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 13:35:04 GMT+0200'),
   "evening": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 19:05:48 GMT+0200'),
   "goldenHour": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 20:57:55 GMT+0200'),
   "sunset": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 21:52:53 GMT+0200'),
   "nauticalDusk": new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 23:57:10 GMT+0200')
};

function getCurrentTimePhase(data, date = new Date()) {
  // Ensure phases are sorted by date and time
  let entries = Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
  // Find index of first phase that is after date
  let i = entries.findIndex(phase => date - phase[1] < 0);
  // Return phase prior to the one found
  // If no prior phase, or none found (i == -1), return last phase
  return entries[i <= 0? entries.length - 1 : i-1][0]; 
}

// Test dates
[new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 01:31:04 GMT+0200'), // Before sunrise, return nauticalDusk
 new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 06:12:12 GMT+0200'), // After sunrise, before goldenHourEnd, return sunrise
 new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 13:35:05 GMT+0200'), // After solarNoon, before evening, return solarNoon
 new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 21:52:54 GMT+0200'), // After sunset, before goldenHourEnd, return sunset
 new Date('Wed Jul 08 2020 23:57:15 GMT+0200')  // After nauticalDusk, return nauticalDusk
].forEach(d => console.log(getCurrentTimePhase(times, d)));
```